# Why is most software dealing with Bézier curves focusing on the cubic ones, to the detriment of other curve orders?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, software-design

When you enter the Bézier curve feature of software like Microsoft Office, LibreOffice, and Blender, they let you create and juxtapose cubic, aka fourth-order, aka 4-control-point, Bézier curves. You click-and-drag creating the two points P0 and P3 and interpolate them, and the last two control points of the convex hull P1 and P2, that are not on the curve, are usually hidden or displayed as handles.

1. Why this focus on cubic (4 points) over quadratic (3 points), quintic (5 points), and higher-order curves?
2. Why is it considered uninteresting to lower or elevate the curve order?
3. When you complicate your curve design you usually join cubic Bézier curves together: this is what happens when you click repeatedly to add points, or subdivide. Why is so little software allowing you to define all your N control points at once, and then interpolate those with a Nth-order Bézier curve? This would be a constraint-based approach in opposition to the traditional "editing" approach (not sure how to word it).

Answer (score 1):

Quadratic béziers allow curves to be joined so they share a tangent line.  But they won't share the curvature. With unequal curvature, highlights and mirror effects will show an ugly discontinuity. The curvature is even more important when the curve is used to control a camera path or a robot trajectory. Cubic béziers can solve that.

Note that quadratic béziers are used in computer graphics, especially in the early days when calculation speed was more limited. For example [TrueType fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) and [Adobe Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) (the animation package that powered many websites until about a decade ago) depend on quadratic béziers.

Quartic curves are defined by 5 points; the curve will go through the end points, and its derivatives will be controlled by 3 more points. With cubic curves, one quickly gets an intuitive feeling of the function of the two controlling points; with a quartic the exact consequence of moving one of the inner control points is harder to guess. And when even more points would be involved, deformations would even be harder to control. Also, the computational cost goes up for curves involving more points.

These deformations are also the main reason why one doesn't use fully interpolating curves. Between the control points, undesired bends are hard to avoid.

PS: Did you check out ["The Beauty of Bézier Curves"](https://youtu.be/aVwxzDHniEw)? For example, starting at 6:18, derivatives are explained. 9:07 deals with the curvature.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the reason number one to join cubic splines (or low degree splines in general) is to maintain "locality" of control points i.e., moving a single control point only affects one segment of the curve or two at most if it is the joint point. That locality property is highly desirable on modeling applications. On the other hand high degree curves gives a more "global" effect to each control point.

I believe the cubic spline in particular gives the best compromise between locality and flexibility of the curve sice it can provide C^2 continuity when joining segments. The quadratic spline is also useful and valuable tool for the right problem but it only provides C^1 continuity when joining the segments, which can be a limitation for complex modeling applications.